# How do I remove a hosted site from firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a hosted site on firebase which I am not using anymore. I still want to keep the project but want to remove the hosted site. Is there any way to do this or do I just need to upload an empty directory. Doesn't seem to be an option in the UI

Comment: You can run `firebase hosting:disable` from the CLI

Comment: That disables the last deployment, but I have a whole list of old deployments I want to get rid of.

Comment: How to enable again after that? firebase hosting: enable?

Comment: To disable a different target / site: `firebase hosting:disable --site <site name>`. Target syntax is usually `hosting:<target>` but in this case I couldn't find a way to specify a target while using the `:disable` command

Answer (score 268, accepted):

It can be deleted.

1. Run `firebase hosting:disable` through the [`firebase-tools`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/) CLI first.
2. Go to Firebase Console and select `Hosting` from the menu of the left.
3. You will see the deployed project with a list of your historical actions like `Deployed`, `disabled`, etc.
4. Only after you have disabled the site, the "three vertical dots" menu will be available for you to choose the action to delete the deployment.

Comment: This seems to have a few votes but I can't test this works any longer. I just changed the billing to the free version so I don't get charged $0.02 a month from google anymore. If someone can confirm that this works for them I'll accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Confirmed, status changes to deleted. When I go to the Usage tab on the same page the my storage size drops, after a few minutes.

Comment: For the record, running `firebase hosting:disable` does **not** delete nor disable Firebase `functions`. I didn't find any documentation and had to try this the  way.

Comment: Is there a way to disable multiple sites? `firebase hosting:disable` seems to only disable the main site for your firebase project

Answer (score 33):

If you have multiple site hosted in same project, then use -s flag to specify the site you want to disable.

```
firebase hosting:disable -s yoursitename
```

Answer (score 11):

## You don't need to upload empty directory.

Just open your project's root directory and enter the following command

```
firebase hosting:disable
```

CLI Response :

```
$ firebase hosting:disable
? Are you sure you want to disable Firebase Hosting for the site xyz
This will immediately make your site inaccessible! Yes
✔  Hosting has been disabled for xyz. Deploy a new version 
to re-enable.
```

This will instantly disable running website also adds a **Disabled** status in release history. Tested on firebase CLI version 9.20.0

Answer (score 7):

**[Update]**

For **multiple site** hosted !! use command

```
firebase hosting:disable --project yoursitename
```

for me it work!! Can your try?

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit hidden, but here are the steps:

1. Go to the [Firebase Hosting console for your project](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/hosting/main), you will see your domain.
2. Hover over your domain. There's an overflow menu (<kbd>⋮</kbd> three vertical dots) on the right.
3. From the overflow menu select <kbd>Delete Domain</kbd>

Comment: That will delete the domain but not the actual deployed site. It is still taking up space on google cloud.

Comment: When you hover over non-active versions of your site in the same Firebase Hosting console, you will also see an overflow menu with the option to delete that deployed version.

Comment: Hmm, I have a lot of previous deployments. That would be pretty painful to go through all of them

Comment: This no longer works. The overflow menu won't appear.

Comment: I just checked and the overflow menu is still there for me. If you're having problems with this, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: works for me too! But would be nice to be able to delete a bunch via CLI

Comment: That sounds useful indeed, so I'd [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: I did `firebase hosting:disable` and it returned with `Hosting has been disabled` Then deleted the deployment in the console. But I can still access the app. Oops, no that was my browser cache. It is deleted

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following command:

```
firebase hosting:disable -s <firebase_project_name>
```

replace `<firebase_project_name>` with the name of your firebase project. This allows you to unsubscribe from the current project and place it in disable mode and you cannot receive traffic from the published web page. When you want to re-enable it, you can do it from the visual platform. I leave an image attached so that you can be guided.

[image]

Comment: There's an extra space between '-s' there in your answer.  But yes, -s lets you specify the site you want to disable from firebase hosting:disable.

Answer (score 4):

## Manually

You can easily go to the console, and click on the 3 vertical dots and delete the site.

[image]

## Using CLI

### Disable only

> Stops serving Firebase Hosting traffic for the active Firebase
> project.
>
> Your project's Hosting URL will display a "Site Not Found" message
> after running this command.

If you want to disable, as the other answers are saying use this command:

```
firebase hosting:disable
```

If you're using multi-sites, you have to specify the project name:

```
firebase hosting:disable --project yoursitename
```

### Delete forever

> Deletes the specified Hosting site.
>
> Deleting a site is a permanent action. If you delete a site, Firebase doesn't maintain records of deployed files or deployment history, and the site cannot be reactivated by you or anyone else.
>
> (Optional) Skip the confirmation prompt by passing the following flags: -f or --force

To delete this site (similar to when you go to the console > delete manually) run this command:

```
firebase hosting:sites:delete yoursitename -f
```

Be careful when using the -f, but if you're running this as a script command, it might be required.

Comment: It is worth noting that you can disable, but not delete the default hosting site. The CLI will output the following error. `Error: HTTP Error: 400, Cannot delete default Hosting Site`

Answer (score 2):

I spent too much time on this and hopefully this can be helpful. I did deploy my stuff using `firebase deploy` however I was not able to see in on the firebase console. When I tried `firebase hosting:disable` I got this `Error: HTTP Error: 400, Invalid project ID specified.`

The steps below helped me delete my project.

- To find the project, you have to get the output of `firebase
  deploy` which will have a console url that looks like this:
  `Project Console:
  https://console.firebase.google.com/project/<your-project-id>/overview`.
- Follow this link and go to project settings. You should be able to
  delete your project in there.

Answer (score 1):

I had to spend several hours removing the default website on Firebase hosting.

The way that I found was :

Enter "firebase init database" in Terminal. It initialize all websites including the default one so that  you can set up a new one.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution in 2024.

- Access the Firebase console and select 'Hosting'.
- View all hosted sites.
- Each site has a '3-dot' menu.
- Click to find and select the 'Delete site' option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A comment suggests changing the billing to free plan. In my case it keeps changing back to "Pay as you go" after successfully selecting the no-cost "Spark" plan.

However I did the following to successfully render my site as not found.

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli
- `firebase login`
- `firebase hosting:disable --project <gcp_project_id>`

[image]

Answer (score -4):

As of now there is no proper way to bulk delete all the previous deployments in a project.

However the best thing you can do is to empty the firebase hosting folder and then deploy it using `firebase deploy`

This option has been given as a feature request to firebase. Lets hope its get implemented soon :)

Comment: You cannot empty the hosting folder. Firebase deploy complains that index.html doesn't exist. And, if you delete the folder entirely the console will not even attempt to deploy hosting. Your only option is to create a blank index.html file and basically deploy a skeleton project. Not ideal.

Answer (score -5):

---

1.Sign in to Firebase, then open your project.

2.Click the Settings icon near project Overview button, then select **Project settings**.

3.In the Your apps card, select the app that you want to delete.

4.Find the Delete Project button from bottom of the page , click **Delete Project**.

5.Check the points , then click Remove app permanently.

---