# Can't deploy vue.js app on firebase - Error: Task failed

Tags: firebase, vue.js, deployment, web-deployment

With [my vue.js app](https://github.com/RichStone/TrackOMAD) I followed the exact steps from the official vue [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#firebase) to build and deploy it on firebase hosting.

My .firebaserc looks as prescribed:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "trackomad"
  }
}
```

However, the deployment gets stuck after one file and exits with the message:

```sh
$ firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'trackomad'...

i  deploying firestore, hosting
i  firestore: checking firestore.rules for compilation errors...
i  firestore: reading indexes from firestore.indexes.json...
✔  firestore: rules file firestore.rules compiled successfully
i  firestore: uploading rules firestore.rules...
✔  firestore: deployed indexes in firestore.indexes.json successfully
i  hosting[trackomad]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[trackomad]: found 9 files in dist
⠸  hosting: uploading new files [1/2] (50%)
Error: Task ce6ebf8fe181eb301634f0abb5063dd4b23f6b1b724d2f85872f69053c6832e8 failed: retries exhausted after 6 attempts
```

This project of mine already had a deployment before that was a simple dummy project as it is provided by firebase documentation. Initially, I tried to just deploy the wholly new vue app over it and got the same errors. I then deleted the old deployment as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44584220/5925094). The only thing that changed is that it now gets stuck at `⠸  hosting: uploading new files [1/2] (50%)` and not as previously at `⠸  hosting: uploading new files [1/4] (25%)`

Can I debug this behaviour somehow or are there any other possibilities to understand what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an incident on hosting, you can see the status here https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Hosting/19015

Comment: Oh, wow, thank you very much for the quick reply on this. How did you get to know about this? Do you have a habit of looking up the hosting provider's status when deployments won't go through?

Comment: A friend that have the same problem say me, I also still waiting for to deploy my project.

Comment: ok, deploy complete after a few hours, it was indeed a problem with firebase hosting..