# I have deleted Firebase Hosting. How do I remove "Site Not Found" from my site?

Tags: firebase, http-status-code-404

I want to use WordPress for my website and Firebase does not support it. I have deleted Firebase hosting from my site using the steps detailed here: [How do I remove a hosted site from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591099/how-do-i-remove-a-hosted-site-from-firebase)

I have also completely deleted my project from Firebase.

Now, when I go to my site, [ug-collective.com](https://ug-collective.com), I see "Site Not Found" with the Firebase logo underneath it, even though I have already set up my site with another hosting platform. I have also deleted the A links from my DNS and added my new host's nameservers and A link.

How do I get my site to stop showing Firebase's 'Site Not Found' message?

Answer (score 0):

Clear your cache and hard reload the website by using <kbd>Ctrl + F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + R</kbd>.
The content is cached in your browser. When I visited your site, it shows me default hostgator page.

[image]

To confirm, you can try opening the site in another browser or an incognito tab.