# Firebase delete Hosting

Tags: web-hosting, firebase-hosting

I hosted a web page on firebase hosting, but I deleted it and the page is still online, how do I remove the hosting from the web?
I followed the steps to delete the project, it was deleted but the page is still online

Please help

Comment: Did you see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591099/how-do-i-remove-a-hosted-site-from-firebase? You might want to see if you can still [undelete the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37578421/how-to-recover-deleted-project-from-firebase-console) to then follow those steps.